# Can a process have initial and final temperatures as the same but not be isothermal? If yes, some examples please

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I am confused whether such a process can exist. By isothermal I mean temperature is constant throughout... please explain simply

Comment: Hint: Consider some thermodynamic cycle...

Comment: your own body before and after a bout with the flu

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "isothermal"  and what you mean by "process".

Comment: @TobiasFünke The OP is asking about a process, not a cycle.

Comment: @BobD Well, it might be a matter of terminology, but isn't a cycle also a process (the converse of course does not hold). I agree though, that if by process they mean different initial and end states; then, obviously, my example fails.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Good point about how we define a process. And that's part of the problem with answering the OP question. IMO by.a process we normally mean a path between two equilibrium states that can be described by a single process equation (e.g., isobaric, isochoric, adiabatic, isothermal) and then a "cycle" would consist of some combination of processes. The trivial case being a single process that is reversed. ,

Comment: Official interpretation of [isothermal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal_process) process is that $dT=0$ at all stages of the process. So, answer is pretty forward - YES, because it doesn't matter if temperature say is "circling around" uniformly,- if it changes at some particular time moment, then by definition what's going in the system is NOT isothermal (at least not in every process path point.

Comment: Both Drake and Kanye stink beyond belief!

Answer (score 5):

> Can a process have initial and final temperatures as the same but not
> be isothermal?

It depends on what you mean by "isothermal" and what you mean by a "process".

Normally when we say "isothermal" we mean the temperature of the system is constant at all times between the initial and final equilibrium states. The following assumes that's what you mean by "isothermal".

If by process you mean any ***path*** between two equilibrium states where the initial and final temperatures are the same, without the path being necessarily "isothermal", then the answer to your question is yes. In fact there are an infinite number of such possible paths.

For one example, involving an ideal gas, you can have a path that combines a reversible isochoric (constant volume) heat extraction process where the pressure is halved, followed by a reversible isobaric (constant pressure) expansion process, where the volume is doubled.  Neither part of the path is isothermal yet the initial and final temperatures are the same.

On the other hand, if by a "process" you mean a path between two states that is described by a *single* process equation (e.g., isobaric, isochoric, adiabatic, isothermal), then the only such path that can begin and end with the same temperature would be, by definition, an isothermal process.

Hope this helps.